# uploading a file using django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I am developing an application with django for uploading a file on the server. I have defined a form and a model in forms.py and models.py files separately as below(respectively):

```
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label=''
    )
```

and in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

    class Document(models.Model):
        docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='targetdir')
```

in my HTML file and my form is:

```
    <form  class="myclass" action="submit" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
</p>


        <br />
            <input font-size="50px" style="zoom:1.5"  class="myclass" dir="rtl" type="submit" value="upload"  id="button" class="top-menu" onclick="pythonhandler()" />
```

now, whenever I submit my form and I wanna to receive my uploaded file on the server via below codes, I got "

```
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'docfile'""
```

error. my views.py file:

```
def pythonhandler(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
                    data = request.FILES.get('docfile') 
                    with open(os.getcwd()+'/mydirectory/'+request.FILES['docfile'].name, 'wb+') as destination:
                        for chunk in request.FILES['docfile'].chunks():
                            destination.write(chunk)
```

I did the mentioned steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531030/multivaluedictkeyerror-in-django) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972606/how-can-i-fix-django-error-multivaluedictkeyerror) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050173/multivaluedictkeyerror-in-django-when-use-post) question, but I receive this error again!

Comment: Please can you be more specific about your html form and views.py?
Did you read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/? Maybe it could be useful.

Comment: I edited my question. I have read your mentioned link and every thing I think is such as that's example. but I have no idea about the error.

Comment: Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the <form> that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". So you miss it in your form tag

Comment: I setted  enctype="multipart/form-data in my form and now every thing is ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed enctype="multipart/form-data" command in my form tag in my HTML file. So, my form in the HTML file must be such as bellow:

```
<form  class="myclass" action="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
</p>
            <input type="submit" value="upload" id="button" class="top-menu" onclick="pythonhandler()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

in your view function

```
def pythonhandler(request):
data = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

and in your html file

```
<form  class="myclass" action="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
</p>
            <input type="submit" value="upload" id="button" class="top-menu" onclick="pythonhandler()" />
```

Comment: The problem was due to enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in my form. the View function is ok.

Comment: jsut gave a smaller way. anyways pleasure that it helped